# massive process on python with Pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm using Pyserial in a program to make a serial interface with RS232. And It already works, but the problem is My device, slave can comunicate any time and to solve that on my code I used

```
while(ser.inWaiting() == 0):
     #wait for some input the read it
     ser.readline()
```

The problem is with that the Python process is too much massive on my CPU. So my question is: How can I do that more "lighter", without all of that process?

Comment: Can you clarify "too much massive on my CPU" ?

Comment: It takes more than 90% of the CPU. I saw that on the terminal of my OS with `top`, I´m using linux, openSuse. And I think that´s the reason. The processor is stuck on that until read somethig.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads. Here is a very simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import time
import sys

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

import os

running = False

def Task1():
  time.sleep(5)
  count = 0
  while running:
    count += 1
    print "Task1 - count is", count
    time.sleep(3)

def Task2():
  while running:
    x = raw_input("Enter some text:")
    print "you entered:", x

def Task3():
  pipe = os.popen('./generate')
  while running:
    a = pipe.readline()
    a = a.strip('\n')
    print "Task3: ", a

t1 = threading.Thread(target = Task1, args=[])
t2 = threading.Thread(target = Task2, args=[])
t3 = threading.Thread(target = Task3, args=[])

running = True
# t2.start()
t1.start()
t3.start()

time.sleep(20)
print "=== exiting ==="
running = False
t1.join()
t3.join()
sys.exit(0)
```

The `generate` program is just (note it uses `-u`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u

import time
import sys

count = 0
while True:
  count += 1
  print "generate count is", count
  time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, PySerial is too heavy to transfer big streams of data. You're better of dropping abstractions and using plain syscalls.

In my application, transmitting at 50 kilobauds with PySerial used 70-80% of a i5-3550 core. Later, the same application rewritten in C using plain `tcsetattr()`, `open()`, `write()` ran in Raspberry Pi without noticeable (as in <1%) CPU usage.

Even using syscalls on Python with the `os` and `termios` modules and maybe even using [CTypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to invoke `cfsetospeed()` and `cfsetispeed()` will provide a massive speedup.